# Floating 2 divs inside of a position relative div

Tags: html, css

I have a question about floating 2 divs inside of a position relative div. They should float left, but it does not work. I tryed it a few times by rewriting the CSS in developer tools. I hope someone can help me. I use the MDL (Material Design Lite) responsive framework from Google Inc. The result should look like in the screenshot. Thanks in advance for your help.

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtZJP.png)

```css
.card-wasserlabor {
  min-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 110px;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.015),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.15),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.015);

  h4 {
    font-size: $card-title;
    color: $dark-text;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-top: 3px;
  }

  .img {
    background: $grey;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 117px;

    img {
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .circle-check {
      background: rgba($black, 0.4);
      height: 56px;
      width: 56px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: calc(50% - 30px);
      top: calc(50% - 25px);

      &:hover {
        background: rgba($red, 1);
      }
    }
```

```html
          <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">
            <div class="mdl-card card-wasserlabor">
              <div class="img">
                  <img src="../assets/cards/card-img-10.png" alt="sera">
                  <div class="circle-check">
                    <i class="material-icons">check</i>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="text">
                <h4>Mittelamerika</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="info">
                <div class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
                  <i class="material-icons">info</i>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: you need to provide the compiled css please.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really run your code, there are too many missing variables to be able to work off of that. So I redid the code. I hope this can help. You just need to manage your widths and float everything left:

Take a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coozin/ok4g78k9/8/).

**EDIT**: *The jsFiddle link was incorrect at first. Reclick this link if code relates to something else entirely*.

**EDIT 2**: *Fixed padding error in code. And replaced jsfiddle link*.

html:

```
<div class="header-area">
  <div style="padding: 20px; ">
    Yellow header
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="element" style="background-color: green; ">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      This is the description
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: red; ">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      This is the description
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element" style="background-color: orange; ">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
    <div class="description">
      <div class="text">
        This is the description
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.header-area{
  background-color: yellow; 
  height: 100px; 
  width: 100%; 
}
.container{
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  float: left; 
  background-color: lightblue;  
}
.element{
  float: left; 
  width: 50%; 
  height: 150px; 

}
img{
  float: left; 
}
.description{
  text-align: center; 
}
.text{
  padding-top: 50px; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @coozin, it helped me a lot to better understand the floating. :) Regards.

Comment: no problem. :) be sure to play with the jsFiddle so you can see how the divs are nested and how the css effects their movement, for example: if you add a border or padding to one of the elements. they will no longer be side by side, you would need to make the width less than 50% to compensate for that extra space taken up in the row

Answer (score 0):

I've made some modifications in your code, hope it can help you to completely achieve your goal:

- To position your text over the img, you need to relative position their parent, and absolute position the text. Then you can move it over the img.
- To easily align the img with the other elements, I think is useful to wrap these elements and give them an inline-block display. Then you can adjust them at the position you want.

```css
.card-wasserlabor {
  min-height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 110px;
  height: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.015),0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.15),0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.015);
  }

  h4 {
    font-size: $card-title;
    color: $dark-text;
  }

  .img {
    background: $grey;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 117px;
    }

    .circle-check {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: rgba($black, 0.4);
      height: 56px;
      width: 56px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      left: calc(50% - 30px);
      top: calc(50% - 25px);

      &:hover {
        background: rgba($red, 1);
      }
      }

.info-wrapper{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--4-col-phone">
            <div class="mdl-card card-wasserlabor">
              <div class="img">
                  <img src="http://sweetclipart.com/multisite/sweetclipart/files/ff0000%20Color%20Square%20RGB%20Red.png" alt="sera" width="100px">
                  <div class="circle-check">
                    <i class="material-icons">check</i>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="info-wrapper">
                <div class="text">
                  <h4>Mittelamerika</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                  <div class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
                    <i class="material-icons">info</i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```